# SQL query to get names containing a and b anywhere in the string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to query my database to get the names of employees which contain both the characters `a` and `b` anywhere in their name string.

I tried the following SQL query, but it did not return all the names that match the criterion I stated above.  How can I change it to return the names I want?

```
select FName
from Employee
where FName like '%a' AND FName like '%b'
```

Comment: `FName LIKE '%a%' AND FName LIKE '%b%'`, and please, write in proper english, don't use `plz`

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! I edited your question to remove internet slang like `plz` and put it into more readable English.  I also put the problem statement up front and formatted the SQL query as code.  It's a good idea to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to get tips on how to write a question that will get you the best help on here.  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you are currently getting 0 rows returned, because you're querying for `FName` values that end with `a` and end with `b`. You're close though.

Just add another wild card to the end of each `like` criteria, and it'll look for matches where anything proceeds, or follows, each letter (including beginning or ending of the string).

`select FName from Employee where FName like '%a%' AND FName like '%b%'`

More information on `LIKE`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

**->** For *Starts with*  use **%** ***after*** the character

```
select FName from Employee where FName like 'a%';
```

**->** For *Ends with* use **%** ***before*** the character

```
select FName from Employee where FName like '%a';
```

**->** For *Anywhere in the String* add **%** ***on both sides*** the character

```
select FName from Employee where FName like '%a%';
```

**SO YOU WILL USE THE 3RD QUERY TO SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM**

```
select FName from Employee where FName like '%a%' AND FName like '%b%'
```